# How to delete run configuration file for a py file that was already deleted in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

I have already deleted the `.py` but in the configuration the file still shows in the run tab in PyCharm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove a "Run/Debug Configuration" go to `Run` `>` `Edit Configurations` select the configuration you want and click the **`-`** minus sign, show in the picture:

[image]

Reference to the PyCharm documentation - ["Create a run/debug configuration"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html#createExplicitly).

Answer (score 2):

Got to "Edit configurations", and select the configuration you want to remove. Then on top you see `+ -`  ... . The `-` key will delete the selected configuration.

The interface style of JetBrain is not so obvious for many people: it uses the macos paradigm and not the Microsoft paradigm. But when you get used on it, you will find also some advantages (being powerful and compact is one).