# Current file targeting function returning an expected default value

Tags: python, path, dirname

I'm trying to use `location_directory= os.path.dirname(os.getcwd())` for a folder location, but this function is returning a directory above, I will explain with results and what I ask for help on how to proceed. The framework what I´m using is dash .
I´m trying to do this :

```
location_diretory= os.path.dirname(os.getcwd())

PATH = f"{location_diretory}/data/"
```

When I try this PATH, return `D:\name\data` but the correct directory is `D:\name\name\data`.

I have 2 diretories in this project, i´m using pycharm for it. The current arquive .py, have the same name in the Diretory "name" and Diretory "name2".

Comment: Did you mean `os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'data')`?

Comment: You just need `"data"` to find a subdirectory of your current working directory with that name. See [What exactly is current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory/66860904) and [Difference between `./` and `~/`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55342466/874188)

Comment: It's advisable to use [`Path.cwd()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.cwd) currently.

Comment: You say in the comment below you are using PyCharm. The current working directory depends on how you are using your [run configurations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration.html) so that's a problem because in the question you don't explain exactly how you are executing you project (from where)? See the screenshot [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66168966) where it says "working directory" in the screenshot is the field you should carefully configure (if you are executing directly from CMD/Shell that's your current working dir..)

Comment: I´m executing the code above in D:\name\name\arquive.py. I want to get data directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you use `location_directory= os.path.dirname(os.getcwd())` actually you search for not the current directory, but you search for parent directory (the directory thet containe the current directory)

use this:

```
location_directory= os.getcwd()
PATH = f"{location_diretory}/data/"
```

Comment: I´m using Pycharm, i tried it, but this return other directory Arquive. I have same name of arquive in diferents directorys called cfg. I tried it but it´s not working for me