# Pycharm wants to use deleted environment

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

My project was using an env named `py35` created by `Anaconda`
Recently I uninstall `Anaconda` and reinstall it again

After uninstall, the env `py35` is gone, for sure
Created a new env named `crawel` after re-installing

I updated the interpreter settings but when I clicked `run` or `debug` button
pycharm shows

```
Error running 'main': Cannot run program "C:\Users\aaaaa\Miniconda3\envs\py35\python.exe" (in directory "C:\Users\aaaaa\Downloads\code\Crawel"): CreateProcess error=2。
```

interpreter settings
[image]

All env list
[image]

Any possible settings I missed?
I tried `Files > invalidate caches / restart`  doesn't help

Comment: Try deleting the `.idea` folder

Comment: What's happening is that a ["run configuration"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66168966) is being executed when you run the project it's not just the interpreter you have configured in the settings. You have to update the run configurations manually to the new interpreter, changing the interpreter in the settings does not update the run configurations.

Comment: wow, thanks @bad_coder, it solved my problems. deleted `.idea` doesn't help